# Is there a sentence where the POS tagging is right, but the word constituent is wrong?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I'm a beginner to Natural Language Processing and I'm reading about **POS tagging and constituents**. I came across conditions where the constituent of a sentence is right but the POS tagging is wrong.

I used the Stanford Parser. http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp

**For example, "Madam, I'm Adam" produces Madam as Adverb which is not right but the constituent is right.**

I'm looking for a sentence where the POS tagging is right but the constituent is wrong.
Can the above condition be possible for any sentence ?

Comment: lolz, this is interesting the OP answered his own interesting question =)

Comment: Yeah. When I asked the question, I wanted the answer. But I found out the answer myself and hence updated it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It is possible to have POS tags right and wrong constituent structure.

Example sentence - They played in the ground with grass turf.

The POS tagging and Constituent are,

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP They))
    (VP (VBD played)
      (PP (IN in)
        (NP (DT the) (NN ground)))
      (PP (IN with)
        (NP (NN grass) (NN turf))))))
```

Which means, 'They played, in the ground, with (the help of/ by using) grass turf'.
But the original constituent structure should be,

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP They))
    (VP (VBD played)
      (PP (IN in)
        (NP (DT the) (NN ground))
            (PP (IN with)
              (NP (NN grass) (NN turf)))))))
```

Which will ideally mean, "They played in the ground (which) had grass turf".

In the first sentence constituent, the grass turf qualifies "They played" and in the second constituent, the grass turf qualifies the ground, which is the appropriate meaning semantically.

This sentence is slightly ambiguous with the absence of a comma. But it is syntactically and semantically right.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are different ways to divide up a given string into smaller and smaller substrings, it is no surprise that a correct POS-tagging of a given string of words may be assigned an incorrect constituent structure.

The example given by @Sherlocked is a case of syntactic ambiguity where one meaning is preferable to the other(s). Another case of this kind is the noun phrase *the advisory committee members* in the sentence in (1).

> (1) The advisory committee members were asked not to talk to the press

On the most natural interpretation of the noun phrase in question, the adjective *advisory* modifies the noun *committee*, which means that a structure where *advisory* and *committee* form a constituent is preferable to a structure where *committee* and *members* form a constituent. (An example where *committee* and *members* should form a constituent is the noun phrase *the tired committee members*.)

To give but one of many possible examples of the case you ask about that doesn’t involve syntactic ambiguity, consider the sentence in (2).

> (2) They wanted him to read the book

According to transformational grammar theories, *him* in (2) should be part of the embedded infinitival clause and not a direct object of the verb *wanted*; one reason for assuming this is that *him* in (2) receives a thematic role from the verb *read*. It is conceivable that a parser would assign the correct POSs to the words in (2) but would assign (2) an incorrect structure where *him* is the direct object of *wanted*. A factor increasing the likelihood of such a mistake is that if we replace *wanted* in (2) by, for example, *told*, the correct structure is one where *him* is the direct object of *told*, since in *They told him to read the book*, *him* received a thematic role from *told*.